# Creating a Text Editor/Ftp client/triple rendering engine all wrapped up in one nice package

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I want to combine the functionality of Notepad++ and Filezilla and maybe even GIMP with the IE, Chrome, and Firefox rendering engines as sort of a Super-Dreamweaver. I am a web designer, and switching between all of these programs slows my progress.

Is anyone aware of any tools that will make this project easier, plugins etc.

I write most applications In C, C++, and primarily C#, I can but prefer not to write java code. I think this project could save me a lot of time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By updating Notepad++ to the latest version the FTP plugin was available. Then I found a browser(lunascape6), that combines the rendering engines of Firefox, IE, and Chrome.